# Multilingual footers with Polylang in the WordPress Astra theme does not work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created separate footers for each language using plugin "Elementor - Header, Footer & Blocks".

All footers are linked to be shown on own language as you can see on screenshot below.
[image]

The problem is that website on all languages have always the same footer, which was last created.

Language settings has all check-boxes selected in "Custom post types and Taxonomies" and "Synchronization".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Polylang, Astra theme, Header and Footer blocks. It just did not show the correct language version.

Today I solved it by using the Theme builder of Elementor Pro (Version 3.0.10) and re-created the Footers there for each language:

[Theme builder 2 language versions of footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXBdb.png)

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

For having a different footer in a second language that you can add whatever you want, you have to:

1. Duplicate the Theme footer file and rename it: footer-fr.php (example)
2. Go to the "templates" folder from your theme and duplicate the footer.php file and rename it: footer-fra.php (I'm gonna use a different name, so you know what file I'm talking about) You can make changes in the "-fra" file in the language you want.
3. In your new footer-fr.php you need to add the footer language, in this example footer-fra:

```
    <?php
        get_template_part( 'templates/footer-fra', 'wrapper' );
    ?>
```

4. Duplicate the Single page file and rename it: page-fr.php (don't forget to add the line: Template Name: Page france). Go to the last line where you can find the

```
<?php 
    get_footer();
```

and add the footer there:

```
<?php 
    get_footer('fr');
```

5. Go to every page you have in the second language and select from Template section: "Page france"